# Unable to connect to K8s Service from another POD

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I am having an issue accessing K8 service from another.

**Core DNS config map**

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-02-19T19:48:57Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "207"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: 6ccfa9bf-da03-4916-ae8c-e49d432a90e4
```

**TCP dump from the node where source service running**

```
20:31:06.339312 IP 192.168.190.8.41456 > 10.96.0.10.domain: 8043+ A? spin-redis-bootstrap.spinnaker.spinnaker.svc.cluster.local. (76)
20:31:06.339504 IP 192.168.190.8.41456 > 10.96.0.10.domain: 8755+ AAAA? spin-redis-bootstrap.spinnaker.spinnaker.svc.cluster.local. (76)
```

Even its not allowing me to ping external URLs like google.com but I could able to ping them with their IP.

Comment: I am trying to install Spinnaker locally and you can find full code under https://github.com/mnuthan1/iac/tree/install-spin

Comment: Are you using the same environment as your github project: Vagrant and Ansible?

Comment: yes, same environment with Vagrant and Ansible